# How to extract top 5 sum values by their top 3 sum reasons please

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I need to review this query:

```
=QUERY('BD3'!A:Q, "SELECT D,Q, 
SUM(M) WHERE I='W34' AND M>0 AND L='Huacho' 
GROUP BY D,Q 
ORDER BY SUM(M) DESC LIMIT 5",-1)
```

I obtain this:

[image]

But I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.